# How to put a parameter in output binding? No value for named parameter 'timestamp'

Tags: java, azure-functions

I have Java based Azure Function. I would like to store service bus message to Azure storage.

I have built blob output and I have now tied add timestamp to file name, but it's failing.

ERROR:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.TopicTriggerDatalakeOutput. 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No value for named parameter 'timestamp'.
```

WORKING:

```
public void run(
    @ServiceBusTopicTrigger(
        name = "message",
        topicName = "MyTopic",
        subscriptionName = "MyTopicSubscription",
        connection = "sbconnstring"
    )
    String message,
    @BlobOutput(
        name = "target", 
        connection = "connstring",
        path = "cont/blob.csv")
        OutputBinding<String> outputItem,
    final ExecutionContext context
)
```

NOT WORKING:

```
public void run(
    @ServiceBusTopicTrigger(
        name = "message",
        topicName = "MyTopic",
        subscriptionName = "MyTopicSubscription",
        connection = "sbconnstring"
    )
    String message,
    @BlobOutput(
        name = "target", 
        connection = "connstring",
        path = "cont/{timestamp}blob.csv")
        OutputBinding<String> outputItem,
    final ExecutionContext context
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to append the current timestamp to file name, you could refer to this doc: [Current time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#current-time).

The expression should be `DateTime` or `DateTime.UtcNow`, and you could format timestamp.

So you could have a try, change the timestamp to DateTime.